# flex layout (using angular material) breaks on some platforms

Tags: html, css, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

The content of my scrolling container stops scrolling when it is, for instance, viewed on an iPad. How can I keep the children from collapsing into themselves and make the  scroll?

I don't know if it's specifically a material issue, or if it's the way flex works on different browsers, but I'm seeing this:

[image: differences between mobile and desktop]

This is a cleaned up version of the HTML output:

```
<md-content class="layout-column flex">
    <div class="layout-column">
        <div class="layout-padding layout-column">
            <div class="layout-column" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
                <div class="layout-margin layout-row">
                    <!--more stuff inside with various layout rules-->
                </div>
                <div class="layout-column">
                    <!--more stuff inside with various layout rules-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</md-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens in some browsers with nested scrolling/flex elements, such as nested md-content elementes